# Merge k sorted vectors

Tags: c++, merge

It might be possible duplicate of other questions, but I didn't find any solutions.
Here is my implementation of merging k sorted lists using a heap which stores iterators on first and last + 1 elements, then extracts minimum, shifts the iterator if needed and updates the state.

Some constraints: length of each array is less than 10 * k and all elements are less than 100.

This is done for interview preparation, so please be patient regarding the code style, bad production practices, e.t.c. Solution doesn't pass some tests, which I cannot show, but eventually it has a runtime error.

```
using int_iterator = typename vector<int>::const_iterator;
using int_range = pair<int_iterator, int_iterator>;

struct comp
{
    bool operator()(const int_range& a, const int_range& b) const
    {
        return *a.first >= *b.first;
    }
};

vector<int> merge_k(const vector<vector<int>>& arrays)
{
    priority_queue<int_range, vector<int_range>, comp> q;

    for(auto& arr: arrays)
    {
        q.push(make_pair(arr.begin(), arr.end()));
    }

    vector<int> result;

    while(!q.empty())
    {
        auto it = q.top();
        result.push_back(*it.first);
        q.pop();

        if(it.first + 1 != it.second)
        {
            ++it.first;
            q.push(make_pair(it.first, it.second));
        }

    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: I believe you will get a runtime error in case any of your "arr"s is empty.

Comment: There is something missing from your C++ question. This would seem to be an actual, specific, C++ question. I don't see anything concrete being asked here.

Comment: Your code is UB. `comp` doesn't provide a strict weak ordering.

Comment: @Aconcagua so instead of copying once, you'd copy them again and again? Looks pretty inefficient for me.

Comment: @Aconcagua Actually O(log(k)), because there are k arrays. I think we cannot compare huge arrays reallocations with simple heap procedures

Comment: @JosephKirtman Sorry, you're right, your code is better than it initially appeared to me. Must be more attentive next time ;)

Answer (score 0):

As denoted in the comments already, there are two issues in your code:

At first, `std::priority_queue` requires strict weak ordering (just as any other sorted container like `std::set` or `std::map`, see notes on [`Compare` template parameter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue)), in other words, elements must not compare equal to themselves. So you need to replace

```
return *a.first >= *b.first;
//              ^^
```

with

```
return *a.first > *b.first;
//              ^
```

At second, you do not consider empty vectors – unless explicitly excluded by the task, you need to do so:

```
for(auto& arr: arrays)
{
    if(!arr.empty()) { /*...*/ }
}
```

Otherwise, `*it.first` will dereference the end iterator and `it.first + 1` increments it.

Optimisation opportunity: avoid reallocations inside the target vector:

```
size_t totalSize = 0;
for(auto& arr: arrays)
{
    if(!arr.empty())
    {
        totalSize += arr.size();
        /*...*/
    }
}
result.reserve(totalSize);
```